# opencv 3.1 drawKeypoints throws errors

Tags: opencv, sift

I use the follow code to run basic SIFT code in opencv3.1:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d/nonfree.hpp>
#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>

#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{        
    //cv::initModule_nonfree();
    //initModule_features2d();
    Mat img_1 = imread("11.bmp", 1);
    Mat img_2 = imread("22.bmp", 1);

    cv::Ptr<Feature2D> f2d = xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();

    //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints:
    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;    
    f2d->detect( img_1, keypoints_1 );
    f2d->detect( img_2, keypoints_2 );

    //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)    
    Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;    
    f2d->compute( img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1 );
    f2d->compute( img_2, keypoints_2, descriptors_2 );

    Mat out0;
    drawKeypoints(img_1, keypoints_1, out0);
    imshow("KeyPoint0.jpg", out0);
    imwrite("KeyPoint0", out0);

    //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using BFMatcher :
    BFMatcher matcher;
    std::vector< DMatch > matches;
    matcher.match( descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches );

    /*
    Mat img_matches;
    drawMatches(img_1,keypoints_1,img_2,keypoints_2,matches,img_matches);
    imshow("matches",img_matches);
    imwrite("matches.jpg",img_matches);
    */
    char c = ' ';
    while ((c = waitKey(0)) != 'q');  // Keep window there until user presses 'q' to quit.

    return 0;

}
```

But the code `drawKeypoints` and `drawMatches` will throw an error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!outImage.empty()) in drawKeypoints, file /Users/vinllen/opt/opencv-3.1.0/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp, line 113
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/vinllen/opt/opencv-3.1.0/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp:113: error: (-215) !outImage.empty() in function drawKeypoints

Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't played with SIFT yet, but it seems you're not instantiating img_matches in this section:

```
Mat img_matches;
drawMatches(img_1,keypoints_1,img_2,keypoints_2,matches,img_matches);
```

The error message hints that it's not expecting an empty() image.
You can try to initialize the image with black pixels first:

```
img_matches = Mat::zeros( img_1.size(), CV_8UC3 );
```

Notice I'm using the first image dimensions/size, assuming both images have the same size. Be sure double check your setup and use the appropriate size.
Additionally you can put the block in a `try...catch` block to see the details:

```
try { 
//your drawKeyPoints code here
}catch (cv::Exception &e) {
cerr << e.msg << endl; 
}
```